# Magento 2 - Setting out the layout of my theme for the homepage

Tags: magento2

I am in the process of creating a new Magento 2 theme.

The Theme is based on the Blank theme which comes with Magento 2.

I'm all sorted with the css and the Theme is working too but I now need to layout the different sections on my main page in a particular order.

My Theme has no layout files so do I have to copy them from Blank and put them inside my Theme?

If so where are they and where do I copy theme too?

Is this all I have to do to set the structure of my pages?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take the reference of Magento Luma theme

For example grab the files from luma theme

```
/vendor/magento/theme-frontend-luma/Magento_Catalog/layout/default.xml
```

Paste it in your theme directory and modify.

```
{mytheme-dir}/Magento_Catalog/layout/default.xml
```

**Other option**

Copy the layout files from core module, for example

```
/vendor/magento/module-cms/view/frontend/layout/cms_index_index.xml
```

Paste it in your theme directory and modify.

```
{mytheme-dir}/Magento_Cms/layout/cms_index_index.xml
```

Make sure your naming convention should match.

For more reference please read [reference guide](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.1/frontend-dev-guide/layouts/layout-types.html)

Comment: What about the 1Column...2Column etc files that are found on Magento 1 ... don't they apply to Magento 2

Comment: you can change in your theme /vendor/magento/module-catalog/view/frontend/layout/catalog_category_view.xml    around line number 8 you can find layout="2columns-left"

Comment: Check the link for adding a new columns or having better idea  http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/118278/creating-a-custom-homepage-template-in-magento2/118363

Comment: My homepage is currently using the 1 Column Layout and the Blank theme as fallback. Where is the layout file please and where do I place it in my theme? Thanks again for your patience...trying to understand this :)

Comment: You can change the layout by  coping /vendor/magento/module-cms/view/frontend/layout/cms_index_index.xml into your theme like {mytheme-dir}/Magento_Cms/layout/cms_index_index.xml and  add like layout="2columns-left"  to page tag, but this is not right approach

Comment: if you want to modify columns of home page go to admin > cms page > select home page > in the design tab > change the layout as well as by selecting custom theme option in the same tab.