# Magento 2 Theming - How are page layout and page configurations connected?

Tags: magento2, layout, theme

I am creating a theme in Magento 2. So far I've figured out how to create a custom page layout for my homepage and how to style it with css. I'm moving on into adding JavaScript and more custom CSS, but I can't figure out how to do this for a specific page.

Every article and document I've come across mentions adding a script or link to the head using the `defaults_head_blocks.xml` or `default.xml`, which is great for something I need globally, but how would I add a script to the head of only one Page Layout?

For clarity and people new to this like me, this is my **theme structure**:

```
<theme_dir>/
  - Magento_Theme/
      - layout/
          - default_head_blocks.xml (as far as I can tell no use in my situation)
          - default.xml (nor this)

      - page_layout/
          - homepage.xml (my target page layout)

    layouts.xml (defines my Homepage layout)
```

Theres more to my theme, but these are the relevant files.

Is there specific naming convention or xml attribute (within `default.xml`) I can use if I want to configure `homepage.xml`? How would I *configure* my `homepage.xml` *page layout*?

**EDIT**
My question is about targeting a specific page layout, this is not a question about coding homepages specifically, it's just an example using my current situation. For example, if I make a custom 'About' page, how do I *figure out* what xml file to override? (keywords 'figure out')

Comment: Your custom `About Page` is a CMS page?

Comment: Edit: actually I think yes, it is a CMS page, as in I edit the content in the CMS. The page layout "About Page" would then be selected in the admin area.

Comment: For the CMS, we can update the XML layout: `CONTENT > Pages > choose a cms page > Design or Custom Design Update (2.1.x)`.

Comment: Thanks again for sticking to this @KhoaTruongDinh! Once again you aren't wrong, but I'm still missing how I would do this with a static file. Such a method maybe doesn't exist for page layouts or I'm approaching this wrong. My thinking is I'd rather keep styling dependent on theme files rather than DB entries.

Comment: Did you ever find a solution for this?

Comment: I just added an "answer", I never found the answer to my question but I've been using that as a workaround.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, we need to read: [putting content in a custom homepage](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/139950/putting-content-in-a-custom-homepage/140073#140073) and [Magento 2 Include js on the product page](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/114327/magento-2-include-js-on-the-product-page/114379#114379)

So, we can add a custom js on home page only:

*app/design/frontend/Vendor/Theme/Magento_Cms/layout/cms_index_index.xml*

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
      xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <head>
        <link src="js/mycustom.js"/>
         <!--<script src="Vendor_Module::js/extension.js"/>-->
    </head>
</page>
```

Or we can call a custom js in phtml:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
      xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
       <referenceContainer name="content">
        <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template"
               name="custom.js" as="custom.js" template="Vendor_Module::custom/js.phtml"/>
       </referenceContainer>
    </body>
</page>
```

In your custom js:

```
require([
        'jquery'
    ], function ($) {
        console.log("Hello Homepage");
    });
```

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to answer my question. You were correct about adding  `Magento_Cms/layout/cms_index_index.xml`, however this appears to effect the homepage of my website regardless of the **layout**. I used homepage as an example, but if I made a new layout for the About page, this answer will not have helped me. Please see my edit.

Answer (score 1):

I don't have a solid answer to this question but I understand to some extend that the layout files relate to Controllers and have similar name structures. [This](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/196861/where-does-magento-look-for-a-controller-when-the-layout-filename-is-bigger-than) question has some hints about how that all works but in some ways only confused me more :(

At this point I do not believe there are specific layout files per each cms page you create, just cms pages in general. My solution has been to use JS to check the current page.

```
$body = jQuery("body");
if ( $body.hasClass("cms-home") ) { 
    // homepage JS
}
```

For CSS I've been doing something similar:

```
body.cms-home {
    /* homepage CSS */
}
```