# Where does Magento look for a controller when the layout filename is bigger than three names?

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, layout

I understand that in my `module/view/frontend/layout` folder, if I create a file called `social_index_index.xml` this file will refer to a controller located at `Social/Controller/Index/Index.php`.

However I currently was looking in the `vendor/magento/module-catalog/view/frontend/layout` folder and I saw a few files with longer names such as `catalog_category_view_type_default.xml` and `catalog_category_view_type_default_without_children.xml`.

What controllers do these files refer to when they are longer names? I do not see a path to a controller for these anywhere.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Looks like you're getting a bit confused with [handles](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/frontend-dev-guide/layouts/layout-overview.html#layout-over-terms), specifically how Magento utilises them.

You referred initially to **social_index_index.xml**. This is actually loaded because in layout there was a handle added - `social_index_index`. This would have come from the auto generated handle formed from the route name, controller name and action name that was then added as a layout handle (this is formed [here](https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/2.2.0/lib/internal/Magento/Framework/App/Request/Http.php#L419) and actually added as a handle [here](https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/2.2.0/lib/internal/Magento/Framework/App/View.php#L145)).

What you're looking at with **catalog_category_view_type_default.xml** is another layout XML file that would be loaded when `catalog_category_view_type_default` is a present handle. This would happen in a category that is not an anchor (no layered navigation) and would have been caused by [this code](https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/2.2.0/app/code/Magento/Catalog/Controller/Category/View.php#L183) in the category view controller.

Another good example to demonstrate this is the `default` handle. How come `default.xml` layout files always apply? Well, Magento leverages handles just like both examples above. You can see the handle added [here](https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/2.2.0/lib/internal/Magento/Framework/View/Result/Page.php#L182)

So handles will load layout XML files with the same identifier (social_index_index -> layout files named social_index_index.xml apply). You could add your own handles (there are many way and places you could do that) and that would get included (catalog_category_view_type_default added by some logic -> layout files named catalog_category_view_type_default.xml apply)

This explanation skips over alot but you seem to have at least a basic understanding of layout so hopefully this all makes sense to you!

Comment: The thing I am still not understanding though is, if I create an xml file at `app/code/Module/Social/view/frontend/layout/social_index_index.xml`, the controller at `Social/Controller/Index/Index.php` will be called. However, with the catalog_category_view_type_default.xml file, there is no file path to a controller. Does this not have a controller? Maybe its an arbitrary handle?

Comment: Yes exactly, it is almost arbritrary. The point is all of them are the same, they're just a handle. In reality, the only difference is that one (`social_index_index`) is auto generated by Magento App logic and the other is added specifically by the category view controller (`catalog_category_view_type_default`) in its controller code

Comment: Don't try to think of them as different because they're not different. They're both handles. The thing to realise is that handles can be added by code anywhere, some of them are automatically generated and others are added in the logic laid out by other code (i.e. is this category layered or not?)

Comment: Okay so one more question. Does catalog_category_view_type_default handle call to the `modules-catalog/Controller/Category/View.php` class? Or does it just not have a controller at all and is just called by other handles? Also, is it possible to have a layout file with just one or two names instead or three or more?

Comment: Handles don't call to anything or necesarilly equate to anything either. Some represent the current route_controller_action (as in the second paragraph), others based on logic (third para) others arbritrarily (fourth para). There is no reason why a handle has to equate to a class so that doesn't really make sense. `modules-catalog/Controller/Category/View.php` happens to add the `catalog_category_view_type_default` handle to the stored list of handles. Other code adds other handles for a multitude of reasons

Comment: If it helps you understand, asking if a handle calls to something is like asking if an array variable calls to something. That is what happens ultimately, [the handles are just stored in an array](https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/2.2.0/lib/internal/Magento/Framework/View/Model/Layout/Merge.php#L238). Other code look to that list of handles to do their thing, for example: Layout code to know which layout files to use

Comment: Okay awesome I think I got it! One more thing, if you have a layout file with route_controller_action name, does it have to have a controller class associated with it? I assume the answer is no. You basically can just add whatever you want for layout files and either add the handle by putting the controller class, or add the handle programatically.

Comment: If it looks like a duck it is probably a duck :) But yes you're observation is on point, you could add the handle in one route/controller/action context that might equate to the auto-generated handle of another route/controller/action context. That would probably cause unexpected side effects but there's nothing stopping you doing that.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/67017/discussion-between-metropolis-and-josh-davenport).

Answer (score 0):

Metropolis first,first,you need understand how this files are merge in the page.

---

> **In the magento2, all the layout files name  in equivalent to  its
>   `Layout Handler name`**   and those  handles are automatically include at respective page and call those handle's xml add via  Magento own logic

**just like:**
 social_index_index  is a handler which  is same page full Action name of that page,which create  during  page under

---

> Some layout files  which is **not related equivalent  handle name** which is
>   **included at page via other handler related  layout file using `<update handle="[NonHandlerLayoutfile.xml]"/>`**

An example:

`vendor/magento/module-sales/view/adminhtml/layout/sales_order_edit_index.xml` of **module sales order  admin edit page**.

Comment: Sorry, I am having a hard time understanding what you are saying here.

Comment: I will  explain  briefly  at tomorrow