# From Default Luma to an actual store - How?

Tags: magento2, product, cms

So, I've successfully installed Magento2, and I see the Luma theme with a Homepage that says `CMS homepage content goes here`.

I added a couple of sample products, but for the life of me I can't get those products to display.  I've tried adding the product list widget to the home page in the CMS, but that doesn't seem to do anything.  And yes, I refreshed the caches and indexes.

Is there a good step-by-step tutorial out there on how to get Magento CE to a state where it can actually act as a store?

Comment: Are the products in stock?

Comment: Yes, and I also believe I set the store to show products that are out of stock.

Comment: Anyway, decided to do opencart.  Thanks all.

Answer (score 2):

1) When downloading Magento source from official site: https://magento.com/tech-resources/download. We can download **Full Release with Sample Data (ZIP with sample data)**. For this option, we will have a beautiful site after installing.

[image]

2) If we download **Full Release (ZIP with no sample data)**, we need to build the data for Homepage, the easiest way to set data for Homepage: **Login to Admin > CONTENT > Page > choose Homepage**. We can see more here: https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/140073/33057

3) If we want to build our data site from "scratch", we should care:

- Category tree, category attributes, product-category association.
- Product, product types, product options, product attributes, product relationship, product price.
- Tax, product tax, customer tax. etc.
- Customer, customer attributes.
- CMS Pages and blocks, banner and widgets.
- Multiple stores, languages, and currencies.
- Payment methods, shipping methods and rates.
- Marketing: promotion, email Marketing.
- etc.

4) Resources:

- http://docs.magento.com/m2/ce/user_guide/magento/magento-community-edition-2.1-user-guide.html
- https://www.packtpub.com/web-development/learning-magento-2-administration

Comment: So, the answer is kinda "no, there's no tutorial unless you buy official training just use the sample data"?

Comment: There's a guide: http://docs.magento.com/m2/ce/user_guide/getting-started.html or you can download Pdf: http://docs.magento.com/m2/ce/user_guide/Resources/pdf/Magento_Community_Edition_2.0_User_Guide.pdf

Comment: Yah, that guide is pretty useless.  "A homepage is where your customer lands first".  Good job telling us what the typical marketing-speak is for various components.  Not so good at describing how to make those show up.