# how to achieve this 2 columns page layout?

Tags: magento2, layout

I try to get a hang of how to design a custom homepage design. I tried the samples I found here [Creating a custom homepage template in Magento2](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/118278/creating-a-custom-homepage-template-in-magento2?noredirect=1&lq=1) and have build a basic custom layout as pointed out. Resulting in a white home-page?

Now what I would like to achieve is a layout which looks like this:

[image: cms homepage layout]

The header can stay as it is on the Luma page.
Than I want two equal columns. In which per example can be (in the left one) text from the cms editor and in the left one a block or widget or also text from the cms editor.
Than a block showing 4 or 5 latest products
And the footer as on the luma page.

Now I have:

app/design/frontend//mytheme/Magento_Theme/Page_layout/custom_home.xml
app/design/frontend//mytheme/Magento_Theme
app/design/frontend//mytheme/Magento_Theme/layouts.xml

So how to achieve this? :)

this is my custom_theme structure:
[image: custom_theme structure]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve all of above without creating a new page layout which is preferable in my opinion. I will only create a custom layout if a very complex layout structure is required which is not achievable through already available layout pages. Magento's layout instructions let you re-use, modify and change layout by using layout instructions.

In your case you can use 1 column page layout and add layout instructions in `app/design/frontend/<Vendor>/<theme>/Magento_Cms/layout/cms_index_index.xml` file to achieve what you require. Let's say you have two cms static blocks with id "cms_block_1" and "cms_block_2", you can use below code:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?> 
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
<body>         
<referenceContainer name="content">
        <block name="cms.block1" before="-" class="Magento\Cms\Block\Block" cacheable="true">
            <arguments>
                <argument name="block_id" xsi:type="string">cms_block_1</argument>
            </arguments>
        </block>

      <block name="cms.block2" after="cms.block1" class="Magento\Cms\Block\Block" cacheable="true">
            <arguments>
                <argument name="block_id" xsi:type="string">cms_block_2</argument>
            </arguments>
        </block>
    </referenceContainer>
    </body>
</page>
```

Similarly you can create another CMS static block and show it after `cms.block2` which will position it at the bottom. You can use css to position block one and block 2 parallel to each other.

Comment: Ok that sounds good. For the "user - customer" this means that only the blocks will be edited and not the homepage_cms, right? I will give it a try and see how this works out for me. Thanks. 
Maybe a dumb question but, If I want this applied for an other (new created) cms page can I just create the cms_newpage_newpage.xml ?

Comment: Yes user can edit the concerned blocks, you should name them so they're easy to recognize. You can create new page layout under Magento_Theme/page_layout and select it in the admin panel. You can use existing 1 column code and make edits if you need to. If helpful please accept the answer and upvote so answer doesn't get littered and someone else can also benefit from it :)

Comment: Hi, its sure use-full but I can not get it to work. I created the blocks as mentioned.  Also the have the cms_index_index.xml in place as above. And cleared all cache. Not getting this in the home_page? The old text and widget are still there? What Am I missing here? How would I get this only for the "custom layout applied than?

Comment: Are you using correct page layout file "1 column", you can confirm in admin for home page under Design. Secondly, are you using all required xml tags etc in cms_index_index.xml file that include <page> and <body> tags! If followed all steps correctly it should work as normal.

Comment: My fault,  think I did not include the required xml tags. I will add them and see how that works-out.

Comment: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
    <cms_index_index>
<referenceContainer name="content"><inserted your solution here>
</referenceContainer>
 </cms_index_index>
    </body>
</page>

This is how I have it now but this is not working?

Comment: Just edited my answer (code) above.

Comment: Still not getting it to work. Can I test this on an other page than the homepage?

Comment: Is your custom theme setup correctly? Is static content deployed correctly, these are the things I'll be looking at. You can test it by making changes to css(less) files and then by deploying using bin/magento setup:static-content deploy command.

Comment: php /var/www/html/bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy 

That seems to be ok.  only one error mentioned in my custom_theme.
Successful: 2149 files; errors: 1
In the syslog file I see this error:
main.INFO: Cache file with merged layout: LAYOUT_frontend_STORE2_4c7461af04bb11fe209659d7147d2c579 and handles default, cms_index_index, cms_page_view, cms_index_index_id_home: Please correct the XML data and try again.
Could there still be an error in my xml?

Comment: I wouldn't worry too much about the syslog layout errors. Just need to make sure your theme is working and layout instructions are getting executed correctly.
Here is a suggestion to test, go into app/design/frontend/<Vendor>/<theme>/Magento_Theme/layout/default.xml file and add following instruction <referenceBlock name="advanced-search-link" remove="true" />. Remove pub/static folder and issue static-content deploy command. Refresh cache and that should remove the advanced search link from underneath the search bar.

Comment: I tried <referenceBlock name="advanced-search-link" remove="true" /> but than I realised there is no such link on may page? decided to try this instead: <referenceBlock name="footer_links" remove="true"/> 
no result. Cleared all the cache and static files but nothing happens.

Comment: which brings us to the conclusion, your theme isn't setup properly hence no layout instructions are working. I'll advise you refer to the DevDocs to setup theme, perform tests and when your custom theme is working you can then apply above code (which is correct) to implement page layout as intended :)

Comment: I also tried this with the "Luma" theme and that did not work either? So where to look? I think my custom theme is set-up correct (the css applies etc.).

Comment: Added my custom_theme structure to my question

Comment: What is the absolute patch of your theme's registration.php file?

Comment: /html/app/design/frontend/MenesTemplate/menes_theme/registration.php

Comment: copy & paste code from my answer in cms_index_index.xml file, remove pub/static folder, remove var/cache/*, var/generation/*, var/view_preprocessed/* directories. Issue bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy command, clear cache, reload and test. You can use remove layout instruction for test.

Comment: I did all that an still no result!

Comment: Had a look at pub/static/frontend/Mytemplate/my_theme/Magento_Theme/  should there also be a xml file created after the files are generated again?

Comment: I got the cms_index_index.xml working (default still not working).  Having a fresh look, I noticed a miner mistake in the cms.block xml notation. So now the created blocks are shown. But beneath each other. And without its own <div> so can't style them with css. How to add a surrounding <div class>? Do I need a template .phtml or can this be added to the xml? Also if I want this for an other cms page will it work just create a xml file named cms_othercmspage_othercmspage.xml?

Comment: Glad it's finally working for you. You can add divs to the content block in CMS page/block then add css to position them as required !

Comment: Just one more question? Can I include a template into the xml for the block? So the user can create a block in the admin without having to add a <div class=""> </div> into the html part of the editor? So in the template there would just be the html markup for the <div> part ? Is that possible?

Comment: of course, create a new question, this thread is becoming way to big :)

Comment: Ok will do that :)