# Add a static block through xml to a specific cms_page?

Tags: magento2, xml, cms-block, cms-pages

From a previous question I learned how to add some static blocks to the CMS homepage like this: [how to achieve this 2 columns page layout?](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/143427/how-to-achieve-this-2-columns-page-layout)

The **xml** is created in:

```
app/design/frontend/<Vendor>/<theme>/Magento_Cms/layout/cms_index_index.xml
```

Now if I want to have the same for other new created CMS page how to achieve that?

What would be the name for the **xml** file? I have tried things like `cms_contact_contact.xml` but that did not work?

Any suggestions?

Comment: You can add layout xml code to particular cms pages from admin. open cms page which you want to update, you can add.

Comment: I know that way but as referred to, I would like to achieve that trough a xml file such as cms_index_index.xml

Comment: Which page you need to it ?

Comment: That does not matter so much. Just a (new created) cms page. See the example I referred to in my above question.

Comment: Then you have to include on every page and display it conditionally if page is cms, block is display other wise not display.

Comment: that could also be a solution, but its not what I'm asking for in my question. I want to have an xml file for lets say a new cms-page with id:more_info. Than I would assume creating a file cms_more_info.xml would be used by that cms-page only?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/48225/discussion-between-s-h-patel-and-mr-typo3).

Answer (score 2):

You can directly add static block to cms page.

In backend, go to

> Content -> CMS Page

Click on specific CMS page,

inside page,

go to `Design Tab`,

**Set Layout Update XML code,**

```
<referenceContainer name="content">
    <block class="Magento\Cms\Block\Block" name="block_identifier">
        <arguments>
            <argument name="block_id" xsi:type="string">static_block_id</argument>
        </arguments>
    </block>
</referenceContainer>
```

In above xml code, **`Replace static_block_id with your block id`**.
Remove cache and check for specific page.

Your Block content are display only specific page.

Comment: I understand but its not an question to my answer. I would like to know how to get that through a xml file similar as cms_index_index.xml which is only applied to the cms homepage ? So how to get a similar xml.file which will be used by a specific named cms-page?