# How to Create custom home page template in magento 2.0.15

Tags: magento-2.1, php, wordpress

I try this solution but i can not get `custom _home` layout according your answer so please help me to solve this problem.

I tried this [link](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/118278/creating-a-custom-homepage-template-in-magento2) and put you `layout.xml` code on this location `D:\wamp64\www\magento\app\design\frontend\Magento\Custom\Magento_Theme'

and added ypur `custom_home.xml` code on this location 
`D:\wamp64\www\magento\app\design\frontend\Magento\Custom\Magento_Theme\page_layout`

Answer (score 0):

We should focus on two xml files: layouts.xml and page_layout/homepage-layout.xml under Magento_Theme folder.

**Create homepage-layout.xml in:**

```
app/design/frontend/_YOUR_VENDOR_/_YOUR_THEME_/Magento_Theme/page_layout/homepage-layout.xml
```

with content:

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<layout xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_layout.xsd">
    <update handle="empty"/>
    <referenceContainer name="page.wrapper">
        <container name="header.container" as="header_container" label="Page Header Container"  htmlTag="header" htmlClass="page-header" before="main.content"/>
        <container name="page.top" as="page_top" label="After Page Header" after="header.container"/>
        <container name="footer-container" as="footer" before="before.body.end" label="Page Footer Container" htmlTag="footer" htmlClass="page-footer" />
    </referenceContainer>
</layout>
```

Our layout is based off the empty page layout, you can also create a layout based another layout.
Just replace `<update handle=”empty”/>` with the layout you wish to use, e.g `<update handle=”3columns”/>`

**Create layouts.xml in:**

app/design/frontend/_YOUR_VENDOR/_YOUR_THEME_/Magento_Theme/layouts.xml
with content:

```
<page_layouts xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/PageLayout/etc/layouts.xsd">
    <layout id="homepage-layout">
        <label translate="true">Homepage Layout</label>
    </layout>
</page_layouts>
```

Now, our custom layout is in the list of layouts.

**Clear cache :)**

PS. this is from my post [Magento 2 Custom CMS page layout](http://inchoo.net/magento-2/magento-2-custom-cms-page-layout/)

Comment: Hi, I all ready add this to file , but still not showing custom layout

Comment: Run setup static deploy and clear cache :)