# Magento 2.3.2 not loading my custom layout

Tags: magento2, layout, magento2.3, theme

I'm trying to override the customer login layout with no success. Magento for some reason is not loading my layout. I'm using Magento 2.3.2.

This is my theme structure:

[image]

I'm following this guide: https://belvg.com/blog/overriding-layout-files-in-magento-2.html with no success. Indeed, the steps are pretty straightforward and simple to understand.

I tried everything, even broken the XML syntax to get some error on screen, but nothing. I tried with cache:flush and setup:upgrade after every change.

Hope you can help me, thanks!

Comment: Your custom theme is activated?

Comment: @Mitro yes is activated

Comment: Are you sure, On frontend your custom theme is enable by checking view source code. Please check because if it is enable then your xml must have to work.

Comment: @Mitro https://imgur.com/a/bhuxBy2 Indeed, I tried this guide https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/118363/77158 defining a custom layout for my Homepage and it works (after selected on the backoffice). But for some reason it doesn't work with the customer login